# compile a 32 bit JAR file in 64 bit Ubuntu in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, 32bit-64bit, executable-jar

I just create a simple GUI java program in my ubuntu. I want to make JAR file from my ubuntu that can be executed on a 32 bit or a 64 bit windows. I have java8 installed in my ubuntu and i'm using netbeans as an IDE. is it really possible to compile a 32 bit jar file in a 64 bit OS.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiled java class files are platform independent, so they will run on both x32 and x64 machines. The JVM is the one that defines used architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Jar files have no 32-bit or 64-bit distinction. The JRE that runs them can be 32-bit or 64-bit, but that has nothing to do with the Java bytecode.

If you're not using any native code, then your jar file will work just fine on both platforms.